# Why I can't use New->Source Folder in a new created maven webapp project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a new maven webapp project in Eclipse, and there is src/main/resources folder and no src/main/java, so I right-clicked on the project folder and choose "New"->"Source Folder". When I type "src/main/java" I just get an error:

> The folder is already a source folder.

and I found in my project's "Java Build Path" property there is a configuration of src/main/java
[image: Java Build Path]
why the project have this configuration while there is no such folder like src/main/java?

Comment: Maven Web Application projects don't have a `/src/main/java/` by default.  Instead, they have a `/src/main/webapp/` folder, which is where JSPs and the like live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the folder as an ordinary folder using `New > Folder`. Eclipse will know it's a source folder when it's in a Maven project.

This is a somewhat weird situation when Eclipse *internally* recognizes `src/main/java` as a source folder because Maven says it's a source folder even though the folder does not actually exist. Because it does not exist, *you won't see it listed as a source folder in project browser / package explorer* - but you'll be given this error when you try to create it. In the moment you create the folder as an ordinary folder, Eclipse will realize this is the missing source folder and list it as such in GUI.

Comment: Yeah, It's really a weird function of the m2e plugin when it tells eclipse to  treat src/main/java as a default src folder but doesn't create the src/man/java folder by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the error because the folder does not exist. Just create the folder and then right click on the folder and select

```
Build Path -> Use as source folder
```

If that doesn't work just remove the folders that say "missing" and do the above procedure on the actual folders

Answer (score 0):

This is absurd, but following worked for me:

- Create a normal folder: New -> Folder
- Delete that folder
- Create new source folder: New -> Source Folder